# Como retroceder dias no datetime, python?

Tags: python, datetime

Preciso retornar uma string no formato "dd/mm/yyyy" em python, consegui através da biblioteca *datetime*.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

Porém necessito também da data 7 dias atras, uma semana anterior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte, [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
import datetime

date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
seven_days_ago = date_now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
print('now:', date_now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")) # 02/01/18
print('7 dias atrás:', seven_days_ago.strftime("%d/%m/%y")) # 26/12/17
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/DraftyGroundedBasil)

Comment: Vlw foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: De nada @ViniciusMorais, bom ano